# Ingress object for redirecting service

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

I am trying to create a nginx ingress object for k8s that catches 6 domains and redirects them to a single URL. I have created the Ingress object as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: "https://www.test.com/products/product1/“
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: review.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: redirect-service
            port:
              number: 443
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - host: calreview.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: redirect-service
            port:
              number: 443
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - host: loureview.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: redirect-service
            port:
              number: 443
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - host: nevreview.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: redirect-service
            port:
              number: 443
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - host: nextreview.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: redirect-service
            port:
              number: 443
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - host: okreview.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: redirect-service
            port:
              number: 443
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

And the backend service as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redirect-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: test.com
```

It all successfully deploys to a local cluster for testing however when i try to do `curl -I nevreview.domain.com` it returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://nevreview.domain.com/
```

Which is clearly not returning the fixed URL of https://www.test.com/products/product1/. Am I handling the redirect correctly, defining the redirect address in the correct place and is there a way to get the service to handle the definition of the address. Thanks a million times over in advance.